# Find text in column A e.g. ID number "10502"

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I currently have a list of employees which have completed training within the whole company. I am trying to create a macro to find the employees with my department via their employee number and copy them over to Worksheet 2.

Employee Number is in column A. This employee may have multiple entries under their ID. I want to copy all information on that row from Column A to Column N. I than want to paste those entries into Sheet2.

We have 187 Employees within our department. Any help with finishing this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A1").Activate

' Find the first ID Number
Cells.Find(What:="10503", After:=ActiveCell, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Select
' copy and paste Text2
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Q1) Did you consider using VLOOKUP in the worksheet instead of a macro?

Comment: Q2) Will a particular Employee Number appear more than once in Column A of Sheet1? If it does, do you want multiple rows to show up on Sheet2, or do you want to consolidate the information into a single row?

Comment: Q1) No I didn't. I have used VLOOKUP before wasn't sure the best way to go about this.

Q2) multiple Rows would be good. I am wanting to give this to them showing each course they have completed and when the expiry date is and other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FindandCopyRow()
    Dim targetSh As Worksheet
    Set targetSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "10503" Then     '--->change ID here as required
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=targetSh.Range("A" & targetSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked Perfect. thanks. This will allow me to make them each their own sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I just added some data to @Mrig's answer.

One being the use of `Application.InputBox` which prompts the user to insert the employee number instead of the user editing the code every time.

I also just `Sheet` referencing for the various part of the `For` loop, always good to reference the sheets you are in to avoid consufion for the next user and then Application itself.

```
 Sub FindandCopyRow()

      Dim DataSh As Worksheet
      Set DataSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

      Dim targetSh As Worksheet
      Set targetSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

      Dim EmployeeNumber As Long
      'This allows you to enter an employee number and not have to edit the code every time
      EmployeeNumber = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Enter Employee Number:", Type:=1)

      'Try use descriptive naming for variables.....always
      Dim DataShRowRef As Long

      'Remember to always reference the sheet you are in when counting and copying etc
      For DataShRowRef = 1 To DataSh.Cells(DataSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

           If DataSh.Cells(DataShRowRef, 1).Value = EmployeeNumber Then

                DataSh.Rows(DataShRowRef).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=targetSh.Range("A" & targetSh.Cells(targetSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)

           End If

      Next DataShRowRef

 End Sub
```